# How can I insert random numbers in specific place in text of UI Text?

Tags: unity

[image: Dialogue System]

I have a Canvas with Text and a Panel.
I want that it will show random numbers between 3 and 10 between the almost and hours:

> Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost...hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game.

Sometimes when running the game I was sleeping for almost 5 hours and sometimes when running the game I was sleeping for almost 3 hours.

For example:

> Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost 5 hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game.

Instead the 3 dots to add a random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with what else is stated in other answers, you may want to write out the number (eg. “three hours”) which you can do with a simple array of options:

```
private static readonly string[] _numberNames = new string[]{"two","three","four","five","six"};

void Start() {
  string numberName = _numberNames[Random.Range(0, _numberNames.Length)];
  textbox.text = string.Format("Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost {0} hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game.", numberName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use string interpolation in your code.

See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Or simply do something like

`"Sometimes when running the game I was sleeping for almost 5 hours and sometimes when running the game I was sleeping for almost" + myVar + "hours."`

Then simply set the string to your text component.

To get a random number:

`int myVar = Random.Range(0, 24);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that can access the Text component and alter it's text based on input, attach the below script the the same GameObject that contains the Text UI Component

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomText : MonoBehaviour
{   
    //I'm using a vector2Int to store the hour range but you could use two seperate Ints if you like.
    public Vector2Int hourRange;

    private int randomHours;
    private Text textField;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        //get a reference to the Text Component, for example this script is on the same object
        //as the Text component
        textField = GetComponent<Text>();

        //set the hours to pick between
        SetHourRange(hourRange.x, hourRange.y);

        //access the Text Components text property and concatenate the randomly chosen hour value to the sentence.
        SetText("Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost " + randomHours + " hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game");

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SetHourRange(hourRange.x, hourRange.y);
            SetText("Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost " + randomHours + " hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game");
        }
    }

    //You can use this function in other scripts to set the hour range
    public void SetHourRange(int minHours, int maxHours)
    {
        randomHours = Random.Range(minHours, maxHours);
    }

    //You can use this function in other scripts to set the text field
    public void SetText(string _text)
    {
        if (textField)
        {
            textField.text = _text;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also control this script from elsewhere by getting a reference to it and calling the set hours and/or set Text functions or combine them into one.